# clientaccesspolicy.xml suddenly stopped working (WCF/Silverlight)

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis-7

Very frustrated with all of this, hoping someone can assist.

I had a Silverlight application and WCF working together without issue for a year. In order to get them working, I had some pain initially but finally worked through it with help. All of the pain came from configuration/security, 401's, cross-domain hell, etc.

The way I have everything setup is that I have a WCF service that resides in it's own application/directory and runs in its own application pool.

On the same web server (IIS7), I have another application/directory with the Silverlight application that points to the aforementioned service.

The server name (for this exercise) is WEBSERVER1. We've created a CNAME for it that is WEB1. In the past, if the user went to http://WEB1/MyApp/ or http://WEBSERVER1/MyApp/ it would work. Suddenly yesterday it started behaving badly. Normal users started getting the Windows challenge/response prompt (and even if they entered the info they would get a 401 error).

My WCF service runs in a site that enables anonymous access (and this has always worked).
My Silverlight application runs in a site that has windows integrated (and this has always worked), since I capture the Windows username when they connect.

For the record, I did create a NEW application pool yesterday with an ASP.NET application that runs in it. This seems to work fine, but there is a chance creating this new application pool and application/directory has caused something to change.

I have a clientaccesspolicy.xml in my wwwroot folder, as well as in the folder for each of the two applications above (just in case). I have tried to promote NTLM over Negotiate as a provider (as that worked for another issue I was having on another server).

After trying some changes, I can't even get the thing to behave the same each time I call it. Sometimes it will prompt me for credentials. Other times it will work, but then say it failed to connect with the WCF service with a "not found". Other times it will actually work fine, but only if I am using the actual server name and not the CNAME. When using the CNAME I always get the crossdomain error, even though I have the cross-domain xml files in every directory root.

This is a nightmare, and makes advanced algorithm analysis seem fun and easy by comparison. Did Microsoft realize how difficult they made this combination of (IIS7/WCF/Silverlight/providers/permissions/cryptic or missing error messages) to get to work??

Comment: Can you run Fiddler and add the log here so we can see what is going on? http://www.fiddler2.com for the download.

Comment: I am actually running Fiddler2, will try to update with the log

Comment: Not sure how to add the log here, but there is one line that looks for the root and gets a 200 (success). The next line looks for /app/Silverlight.js, which returns a 304 (cached?). The next line is a 401 error for /clientaccesspolicy.xml (even though that file is there), and the next line is a 401 for the /crossdomain.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that appears to be working.

In this case, I had to change the authentication mode for the default web site (which hosted the clientaccesspolicy.xml file) from anonymous access to Windows Integrated. I don't understand why this worked for a year or so and then stopped, but it seems to have resolved it.

The new application that I had deployed yesterday was a standard ASP.NET web application, which I put in it's own application directory and it's own application pool, to ensure that it would not cause this sort of issue. I'm still not even sure if it did.

The way I resolved it was by trying to navigate from my PC to the actual http://servername/clientaccesspolicy.xml file, and that was giving me a 401 error. I switched from anonymous to windows integrated on that default website (which has nothing in it except for that xml file) and that resolved the permission issue. I then had to permission the actual AD groups to have read access to that folder (if not they got the user/pw prompt and could not get through).